# Listview CommandName applied to table

Tags: html, asp.net, listview

I'm using the following ListView markup to render a table for each object retrieved from a database...

```
<asp:ListView ID="daysListview" runat="server" Visible="false" OnItemCommand="weeksListViewCommand" DataKeyNames="date, weekID, entryID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table  style="background-color:#2E425F; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:5px; padding-left:5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #7795BF">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:120px"><asp:LinkButton ID="dayNameLinkButton" style="color:White; font-size:14pt" CssClass="dateLinkText" runat="server" CommandName="dayClickCommand"><%#Eval("dayOfWeek") %></asp:LinkButton></td>
                <td align="right" style="width:150px"><asp:LinkButton ID="dayLinkButton" CssClass="dateLinkText" runat="server" CommandName="dayClickCommand"><%#Eval("dateFormatted") %></asp:LinkButton></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="jobDescLabel" runat="server"><%#Eval ("jobDescription") %></asp:Label> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="dayStatusLabel" CssClass="completeTxt" runat="server"><%#Eval("entryHalfDayString") %><%#Eval("entryFullDayString") %></asp:Label></td>
                <td align="right" style="color:White; font-size:9pt"><asp:LinkButton ID="deleteEntry" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size=9pt CommandName="deleteEntry" Text="delete"></asp:LinkButton></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Clicking dayNameLinkButton or dayLinkButton runs dayClickCommand. What I would like is for a click anywhere to result in the dayClickCommand command being run. CommandName is not a property of table so there does not appear to be a simple way of doing this.

Anyone know a way or a workaround that I might be able to use?

Many Thanks

Comment: You can use <asp:linkbutton> as outer tag to your <table> tag. So that your link button will be having commandname dayClickCommand, click on the content of that link button causes dayClickCommand to run.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Didn't realise Link Button could be used as a wrapper.